# Retrofit model set of JSON values

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am building an Android application that uses Retrofit to get information from a web service. Many of responses given have this structure:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "result": {
        "101": {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "phone": 6235974002,
            "email": "john@doe.com"
        },
        "118": {
            "id": 118,
            "name": "Peter",
            "surname": "Parker",
            "phone": 6589325074,
            "email": "peter@parker.com"
        },
        "130": {
            "id": 130,
            "name": "Foo",
            "surname": "Gar",
            "phone": 6998531452,
            "email": "foo@bar.com"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I model this kind of "result" value? I tried to set it as array, but app throws an exception. Currently my model for this response is this:

```
@Parcel
public class ActivityResponse
{
    @SerializedName("status")
    private int status;

    @SerializedName("result")
    private ArrayList<User> result;

    public int getStatus () {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus (int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getResult () {
        return this.result;
    }

    public void setResult (ArrayList<User> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Result is not a collection, it's an object with properties 101, 118, 130. Are these fields constant or are they dynamic? If they are dynamic, this web service is not very usable as it seems like those should be fields inside an array of that inner object.

Comment: Yes. 101, 118 and 130 are dynamic values result of this call. Thus, should I treat JSON responses directly instead of Retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the data returned from the service is less than stellar - it looks like it should be a collection instead of an object as the ID is already in the child object. Regardless, a `Map` is the solution here given the JSON response.

```
@SerializedName("result")
private Map<Integer, User> result;
```

This should then allow you to retrieve each `User` object.

Comment: Thanks, sorry get mixed up with C# sometimes, will make that edit now

Comment: I have this error: Error:(22, 40) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type java.util.Map<java.lang.String,org.example.models.User> for org.example.ActivityResponse.result